# Proper way to set select list value in an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, selectlistitem

Most examples I've seen of how to use `DropDownListFor` show a model with an `IEnumerable` or `List` of `SelectListItem`'s, and you can set the `Selected` property for the item you want to be initially displayed.

What is the (or a) proper way to do this for an array of dropdowns? I suppose I could make an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SelectList>>` so each dropdown has it's on `IEnumerable<SelectList>>` with the appropriate value selected but that just doesn't seem right.

I think it would have made a lot of sense for the `DropDownListFor` method to have an overload letting you set a default value. The best solution I can think of at the moment is to simply set the default value for the proper item (and clear the selected value for all others) just before calling `DropDownListFor`.

But surely there is a more appropriate way to do it? Or perhaps `DropDownListFor` just isn't appropriate for this job and straight html would be easier?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of DropDownListFor I usually use

```
<select class="form-control" id="itemId" asp-for="@Model.ItemId" 
asp-items="@Model.Items"></select>
```

where Items = List< SelectListItem >. It automatically select  ItemId from  Value of select  list and shows a proper text.

Comment: +1 because that would have been a good answer if I were using core. I've added another tag to specify that this is for framework version 4.5.2 though. I did try it but no dice. :/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding a line of code in the view directly above the `DropDownListFor` statement to change the selected item like so:

`Model.ExpenseCategories.ForEach(cat => cat.Selected = cat.Value == item.CategoryName);`

Seems like there ought to be a better way to do it, but this was a pretty simple solution. I'll wait a bit before accepting my own answer in case anyone else has a better way to do it.